# valid palette required for paletted images

Tags: c++, c, libpng

When using `libpng` to write a PNG image that uses a colour palette (`PNG_COLOR_TYPE_PALETTE`), I see the error:

> valid palette required for paletted images

What causes this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you call `png_set_PLTE` *before* calling `png_write_info`.

For example:

```
// Set the colour palette to use
unsigned paletteSize = ...;

assert(paletteSize <= PNG_MAX_PALETTE_LENGTH);

png_color* palette = (png_color*)png_malloc(png_ptr, paletteSize*sizeof(png_color));

for (unsigned p = 0; p < paletteSize; p++)
{
  png_color* col = &palette[p];
  col->red = ...;
  col->green = ...;
  col->blue = ...;
}

png_set_PLTE(png_ptr, info_ptr, palette, paletteSize);

png_write_info(png_ptr, info_ptr);

// ... png_write_image, png_write_end

png_destroy_write_struct(&png_ptr, &info_ptr);

png_free(png_ptr, palette);
```

Comment: How do you determine what color represents what binary value ? Like in a 1 bit depth, would the first color of the palette by the zero bit and the second color be the one bit ?

Comment: Not sure whether monochrome is special-cased. Have you tried a palette size of 2 and explicitly setting the RGB values to black and white?

Comment: I tried it out, for 1 bit palette image, the first color in the palette corresponds to a `0` bit and the second the `1` bit, as expected.